# spritekit print something at specific time intervals for a certain amount of time using skaction

Tags: swift2, skaction

I created a simple action sequence that will perform a few tasks on a sprite object, but i would also like to make a custom action within the sequence that will print something for a certain number a seconds seconds at specific time intervals intervals (e.g print "hello world" for 10 seconds at 1 second intervals). I tried creating a method that returns an skaction, but that didnt work, and the action ran at when the sequence was first called instead of after the preceding action finished. Here's what i got so far

```
let printAction = SKAction.customActionWithDuration(10) { (SKNode, CGFloat) -> Void in
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("printit"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
    sprite.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([printAction,scale,printAction])))
    func printit() {
        print("hello world")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are combining two approaches that can solve your problem individually but the combination you're making will not work.  (you are triggering multiple 1 second timers from an action that will call your capture block an unpredictable number of times at an uncontrollable speed).

Solution using SKAction:

```
let printMessage = SKAction.runBlock(){ self.printIt() }
let wait         = SKAction.waitwaitForDuration(1)
let printCycle   = SKAction.sequence([printMessage, wait])
self.runAction(SKAction.repeatAction(printCycle, count:10))

func printIt()
{
   print("hello world")
}
```

solution using NSTimer:

```
for time in 0..<10
{
  NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(Double(time)),
          target: self, selector: Selector("printIt:"), 
        userInfo: nil,   repeats: false)
}

func printIt(_ : NSTimer) 
{
   print("hello world")
}
```

In a Sprite Kit environment, I would recommend that you don't mix frameworks and go with the SKAction approach.   It will make it easier to control/clean-up the game environment by linking everything to your SKScene and/or SKView